# In ASMX service how to change ResponseHeader ElementName

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I am creating ASMX web service in .Net for javaclient. Provided soap looks like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pus="http://www.example.org/pusheventservice/">
<soapenv:Header>
<ServiceHeader>
<TransactionID>258350</TransactionID>
<TransactionDate>2014/12/21</TransactionDate>.......
```

and javaclient expects response SOAP

like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pus="http://www.example.org/pusheventservice/">
<soapenv:Header>
<ResponseServiceHeader>
<TransactionID>258350</TransactionID>
<TransactionDate>2014/12/21</TransactionDate>....
```

means requestElement is 'ServiceHeader' and ResponseElement must be 'ResponseServiceHeader'

I WebMethod i achieved this but unable in Header.

Is it Possible?? If Yes how?? Also I Cant use WCF....

**EDITS**

```
namespace PushWS
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:60463/PushEvent.asmx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
[SoapDocumentService(SoapBindingUse.Literal, SoapParameterStyle.Bare, RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.SoapAction)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PushEvent : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public ServiceHeader serviceHeader = null;
    public SoapUnknownHeader[] userCredentials;
    [WebMethod(Description = "updateEvent receives XML from Client")]
    [SoapHeader("serviceHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
    [SoapHeader("userCredentials", Required = true)]
    [return: XmlElement("EventResponse")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://localhost:60463/PushEvent.asmx/updateEvent",
    RequestElementName = "updateEventRequest",
    ResponseElementName = "updateEventResponse")]
    public XmlElement updateEvent([XmlAnyElement]XmlElement MyPushEvent)
    {
           //Logic here
    }
    public class ServiceHeader : SoapHeader
    {
         public string TransactionID{get;set;}
         public string TransactionDate{get;set;}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Show us how you created your header.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: OK @John, see the edits

Answer (score 1):

Create a derived class for the response header:

```
public class ResponseServiceHeader : ServiceHeader
{
}

public ServiceHeader serviceHeader = null;
public ResponseServiceHeader responseServiceHeader = null;

[SoapHeader("serviceHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.Int)]
[SoapHeader("responseServiceHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.Out)]
```

Comment: this is giving Error, object serviceHeader in WebMethod is null now SoapUnknownHeader[] array receving header element

Comment: I want something like RequestElementName = "ServiceHeader",
    ResponseElementName = "ResponseServiceHeader"......

Comment: Ok, try renaming the class. Or do you want a different header element between the request and the response?

Comment: If I rename the class, then I have to write ResponseServiceHeader in requested SOAP...pls see again my request and response SOAP in ques.

Comment: I really don't understand your question, then. How about you show us what XML you get if you rename the class.

Comment: Renaming class giving null ServiceHeader error. In requested SOAP above...`<ServiceHeader>` is not a keyword its a Class name. If I rename class I have to write `<ResponseServiceHeader>`in REQUESTED SOAP..then this will not proper requested SOAP....I want this in RESPONSE SOAP....

Comment: See my edit. You didn't make it clear that you want a different element on the request than you do on the response.

Comment: Ultimate answer @John. Working like a charm. Now response namespace prefix problem is left, should I post separate question for that?

Comment: Yes. Use a separate question. You have given no information about namespace problems in this one.

Comment: OK @John, I posted new question describing namespace problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957656/asmx-service-namespace-prefix-in-response-soap

Comment: One more problem, I need to add UserName/Password Header also, now Error is saying I cannot add more than One header with `Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In`

Comment: You keep finding more and more reasons to stop using ASMX and use WCF instead.

Comment: I know @John your are encouraging everyone to use WCF and it should be, I too prefer WCF but I cannot change at this point of time. If solution is possible then pls write.

Comment: If I knew of a more practical solution, I would tell you. Right now, it's looking like the next nearest practical solution _is_ WCF. You are simply trying to do things that ASMX will not let you do. Though I'll admit that I'm surprised at this new restriction. I don't recall ever hearing about it before.